# trying to read from a file and split it into words and store those words in an arrayList

Tags: java

in my code when i want to print out the list , there is return of line and i don't know how to get rid of it, for example if my file contain those lines:
i can't think of anything to write
blah blah blah
when i print out my list i got this:
{i, can't, think, of, anything, to, write
blah,blah , blah}

this is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>() ;   
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));){

        int i = 0;

        String str = " ";
        while((i = br.read()) != -1){

            str += (char) i;

            if( (char) i == ' '){

               list.add(str.toString());
               str = " " ;
           }

        }
        list.add(str.toString());

       }catch (Exception e){
           System.out.println("there is an exception ");
       }
    printArrayList(list);
}

public static void printArrayList(ArrayList<String> list){
    System.out.print("{");
    for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){

        if (i > 0)
        System.out.print("," + list.get(i));
        else 
            System.out.print(list.get(i));
    }
    System.out.print("}");


}
```

Comment: what format do you need in ?

Comment: i want to get the list as follow : {i, can't, think, of, anything , to, write, blah,blah,blah} without the return line!

Comment: just change to => if ( **!** list.get(i).contains("\n")) {
     System.out.print("," + list.get(i));
    } ........... if case has "!" ie. does not contain "\n" new line

Comment: it deosn't work either

Comment: works for me . try change it to **if (!list.get(i).contains(System.getProperty("line.separator"))){   print}**

Comment: i got this :  { ,  i  ,  can't  ,  think  ,  of  ,  anything  ,  to  ,  blah  ,  blah}

Comment: there are two words missing!

Comment: ah ok . i was just looking for the space ... didnt count words

Comment: if (i > 0) {

    String data = list.get(i).replace(
      System.getProperty("line.separator"), " , ");
    System.out.print("," + data);
   }

Answer (score 1):

Are you opposed to importing a library?  Apache StringUtils has a method that splits on whitespace, returning everything else in tokens.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are only splitting the sentence when you find a space `if( (char) i == ' ')`. If you want to split it on new lines also, use

`if ( (char) i == ' ' || (char) i == '\n')`

Note: `\n` is not the line separating character in all the platforms. AFAIK, it can be anyone of `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`..

Comment: Did you also try using `\r`?? As I said, `\n` is not the line separator in all platforms...

Comment: yes i tried \r and it's not working, im using eclipse by the way

Comment: '\n' is NOT a char [when read from the file] . "\n" new line is a String

Comment: Try this .... String a = System.getProperty("line.separator");
  char[] c = a.toCharArray();
  System.out.println(c.length); => now that will print size of 2 [that cannot fit in char size of 1]